# Is there any other way of getting a printer's port number apart from using PrintDlg()

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I want to get a printer's port number using win32, I know I can get it using `PrintDlg()` function, but I don't want to use that function in my app. is there any other way of getting it? I have tried to search but nothing is coming up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use it in your app? That might help narrow down alternatives.

Comment: Which specific member of the PRINTDLG struct do you want to obtain? How are you going to specify the printer if there are multiple printers installed?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlga?redirectedfrom=MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-printdlga?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I want to implement my own kind of Dialog like Ms Office, so i wont be using the standard PRINTDLG.

Comment: So you aren't actually interested in just the port.